# How to append data returned from json function to html table using jQuery ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, razor

I work on razor asp.net . I face issue I can't append returned data from json to html table

when try to append table html using jQuery ajax I get error

can't read property of null reading companyname at function.each at object.success

my code details

when display data for first time

```
<table id="myDataTable" class="table" style="margin-top:20px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Branch Name</th>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>User Type</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>@Model.MyData.CompanyName</td>
            <td>@Model.MyData.BranchName</td>
            <td>@Model.MyData.UserName</td>
            <td>@Model.MyData.UserType</td>
            <td>
                <button id="editDataBtn" style="width:100px;" class="btn btn-primary edit-btn" data-id="@Model.MyData.ID">Edit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

to reload data by append on table html i do as below

```
$("#updatedatabtn").click(function () {
                var userId = $("#userId").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '?handler=RefreshDataTable',

                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { UserId: userId },
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                        $("#myDataTable tbody").empty();
                        $.each(result, function (index, item) {
                            $("#myDataTable tbody").append("<tr><td>" + item.CompanyName + "</td><td>" + item.BranchName + "</td><td>" + item.UserName + "</td> </tr>");
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.error("AJAX request failed: " + error);
                    }
                });
            });
    [BindProperty]
    public UserDto MyData { get; set; }

public JsonResult OnGetRefreshDataTable(string UserId)
        {
            var result = userService.GetUserDetails(UserId.ToString());
            MyData = result.Result;
            return new JsonResult(MyData);

        }
```

when call api for RefreshDataTable i get returned data below :

```
{
    "vLoginName": "9595",
    "vPassword": "qvUBTS3WkZ/mFbpDQjQsFjsyLR9ehAEWqLedckm3pKZgUlZ/IsH9PFuDXsOto3dXgByvSXRS9ynsBahj38SSkw==",
    "userMode": "A",
    "id": 230,
    "failedAttempts": 0,
    "userName": "ADC Test User",
    "branchName": "KFoundation-Aweer",
    "branchCode": "101KF06",
    "companyName": "Union Co-Operative Society",
    "userType": "S ",
    "accountStatus": null
}
```

returned for function will return only one object because I display user details .

Issue details image

[image: issue filling or append table]

Updated post
after apply answer posted below
i get data undefined on all rows

```
Company Name    Branch Name User Name   User Type   Actions
undefined   undefined   undefined
undefined   undefined   undefined
undefined   undefined   undefined
undefined   undefined   undefined
undefined   undefined   undefined
undefined   undefined   undefined
undefined   undefined   undefined
undefined   undefined   undefined
undefined   undefined   undefined
```

Comment: thanks for support issue still exist it return multi rows with undefined on all rows and lll columns

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $("#myDataTable tbody").append("<tr><td>" + item.companyName + "</td><td>" + item.branchName + "</td><td>" + item.userName + "</td> </tr>");
```

Update:

> returned for function will return only one object because I display
> user details .

try to modify success  function like:

```
success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                $("#myDataTable tbody").empty();
                $("#myDataTable tbody").append("<tr><td>" + result.companyName + "</td><td>" + result.branchName + "</td><td>" + result.userName + "</td> </tr>");
                //$.each(result, function (index, item) {
                   

                //        $("#myDataTable tbody").append("<tr><td>" + item.companyName + "</td><td>" + item.branchName + "</td><td>" + item.userName + "</td> </tr>");
                  
                //});
            },
```

Comment: @ahmed abdelaziz check with my update answer.

Comment: Hi @ahmed abdelaziz, Is your problem solved ?